# Will it violate copyright if I use an essay question from a book and write my own essay and publish it on my website?

Tags: copyright

Suppose that there is a book by Cambridge or Oxford. In that book, there are some essay samples. I want to take those essay titles and write my own essays for them. Does this violate copyright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laws vary on copyright (as on most things) but it is doubtful that this would be considered a violation if you are quoting (and citing) a short excerpt from a book. Especially if your purpose and context are academic.

First, there are academic/teaching exceptions that make some things more acceptable. Second, I doubt that you would be lessening the value of the original by using a short excerpt (an important consideration in some laws). Third, copyright violation is a civil matter (for most purposes) and I doubt that the publisher would consider it a terrible enough thing to take you to court.

Republishing the essays themselves would probably be a different matter.

There is also the "intent" of the book, which is probably to give ideas to student about the kinds of questions and the kinds of acceptable answers.

However, some publishers are extremely trigger happy on such things, but they tend to be music publishers who object to background music in otherwise harmless home videos on YouTube.

---

Note, additionally, that (some laws) there are some things that can't be copyrighted for various reasons. One reason, that might apply here, depending on those questions, is that there are very few (or even only one) ways to express some thoughts. And thoughts can't be copyrighted. They are public domain by the very nature of them.